# How to Find Available IP Addresses in LAN using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, ip-address, lan

I was trying to develop a message chat application for LAN (Windows Store App)
 using XAML and C#. So, first of all how can I know, the people who are available in LAN
 based on their IP addresses?

Any sample code or idea to achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), i.o.w. [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)). There are C# bindings for Bonjour in the [Bonjour SDK](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour).

Comment: Searched for related articles and samples.. me new to this technology..

Comment: Since it is a Windows Store app, that rules out using software like Bonjour, right? [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using) uses Win32 APIs so that's also not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not rely on multicast using WinRT :(

However you have 2 solutions :

1. Using IP broadcast : send your bonjour message to 255.255.255.255
2. Add a server node

Note that solution 1 works only on LAN and may be limited by routers and gateways configurations.

Comment: Thank you Kronos.. Is there any articles or documents will more helpful to me.

Comment: @Lokesh, If you can install a server (option 2) why not install a jabber server and just make a jabber client with many available APIs. I had a good experience with http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Found this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/75dfa774-54a0-43a4-b489-ddc753d00ca4 It's in C++ but gives you a good track. Simply request a stream to a "host" with address 255.255.255.255 on any given port and write your hello message. All device should listen that port and answer a hello back. I would send a list of known avaible clients by the device while sending my hello message to have a faster discovering service. To sum it up, every device discover and tell others who they already know, so you are more in P2P scenario then client-server.